# Why There Is Long Hash in Git

Tags: git

As you know we can use short hash as commit id.
But I wonder why there is a long hash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hash is that long to reduce risk of collision

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_collision

Comment: If there is a risk of collision why we are using short hash?

Comment: @AltayTuran Just for convenience. If there are two objects in the repository that are identical in the abbreviated form, then you must use a longer abbreviation.

Comment: When Git prints abbreviated hashes, it ensures that they are unique *at the time they are printed*; they could become ambiguous later as the repository grows.